# Can Lerna bump prerelease version according to the Conventional Commits specification?

Tags: javascript, lerna, monorepo, conventional-commits

It doesn't seem that Lerna `3.20.2` is able to bump prerelease versions (e.g. `1.0.0-alpha.0`) according to the [Conventional Commits specification](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/).

I made a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://github.com/customcommander/lerna-prerelease-conventional-commits) if you want to try this out.

Say we have two Lerna-managed repositories, both with three sub-packages. One repo has "production" packages the other has "prerelease" ones:

```
dev (or dev-prerelease)
  |-- packages
  |   |-- major
  |   |   |-- package.json (1.0.0 or 1.0.0-alpha.0)
  |   |-- minor
  |   |   |-- package.json (1.0.0 or 1.0.0-alpha.0)
  |   |-- patch
  |   |   |-- package.json (1.0.0 or 1.0.0-alpha.0)
  |-- package.json
  |-- lerna.json
```

I then make the following commits in both repositories: (commits follow the Conventional Commits specification)

- A breaking change in the major package
- A new feature in the minor package
- A bug fix in the patch package

And run this command in both repositories:

```
npx lerna publish --conventional-commits --yes 2>/dev/null
```

### Observations

The "production" repo sees its packages updated according to the Conventional Commits spec:

```
Changes:
 - major: 1.0.0 => 2.0.0 (private)
 - minor: 1.0.0 => 1.1.0 (private)
 - patch: 1.0.0 => 1.0.1 (private)
```

However in the prerelease repo, all packages are simply "patched":

```
Changes:
 - major: 1.0.0-alpha.0 => 1.0.0-alpha.1 (private)
 - minor: 1.0.0-alpha.0 => 1.0.0-alpha.1 (private)
 - patch: 1.0.0-alpha.0 => 1.0.0-alpha.1 (private)
```

The thread in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1433) seems to suggest that this is a bug (but I'm not sure).

**Question** I'd like the packages in my "prerelease" repo to be updated in the same way as in the "production" repo whilst retaining their prerelease suffix. What am I doing wrong here?

---

You can also follow up this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2536) that I raised

Answer (score 8):

I used the following command:

`lerna publish --conventional-commits --conventional-prerelease`

The version bumps for these flags are explained in the below image:

[image: table-with-conventional-prerelease]

Comment: Running `lerna publish prerelease` bumped my version from `0.3.3-alpha.0` -> `0.3.3-alpha.1`. Adding the `--conventional-commits` flag made no difference to the behaviour.

Comment: @JamieBirch What's your commits before this command? Is there any commit with keyword like BREAKING CHANGE in footer (which makes a major version bump)?

Comment: My previous release was `0.3.3-alpha.0`. From that time onwards, I made 18 commits, and only one of them included a keyword (which was "feat:"). So I think it doesn't examine the commit messages at all; it just decides how to bump the version entirely based on the term that you write in the command, e.g. `prerelease` in the case of `lerna publish prerelease`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue:

you have to go through the lerna versioning commands

- `lerna version major`
- `lerna version premajor`
- `lerna version prerelease`

now you will see that all the changes made it in your `lerna.json` (this is where the actual version is kept, and the `version` command is the only one changing the MAJOR, MINOR and PATCH numbers)